# How to set a connection proxy in JMeter for a single thread group?

Tags: proxy, jmeter

There are at least two ways of setting a connection proxy for JMeter, i.e., in the [command-line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206179/jmeter-how-to-send-xml-request-to-a-server) or in the [HTTP request defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults). Now I would like to set the connection proxy for a SOAP/xml-rpc request only for a single thread group. At the moment, I see only one option: use a regular HTTP request sampler and set all values required for a SOAP request, e.g., SOAP action, in the headers. In doing so, I can define the proxy settings in the aforementioned HTTP request defaults. Is there another better way to achieve this goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the workbench of your testsuite, add an HTTP proxy (Right click on workbench > Non-testing element > HTTP proxy). Within this element, you can set the target controller or test fragment the proxy should be applied to.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you are answering your question ?